# Getting the lowest value of fields with different arrays

Tags: php, arrays, min, google-distancematrix-api

I have created the following array in PHP with help of the Google Distance Matrix API.

Now I need to compare the [`distance`] field, get the lowest value and save the key of the array in a variable. How do I do this?
I looked at [`min()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.min.php) but this doesn't seem to work with multiple arrays.

```
Array
(
[utrecht_cs] => Array
    (
        [name] => utrecht_cs
        [address] => 3511 AX Utrecht, Netherlands
        [distance] => 95
    )

[groningen_cs] => Array
    (
        [name] => groningen_cs
        [address] => 9726 AC Groningen, Netherlands
        [distance] => 102.47
    )

[zwolle_cs] => Array
    (
        [name] => zwolle_cs
        [address] => 8011 CW Zwolle, Netherlands
        [distance] => 2.54
    )

)
```

Comment: Have you at least tried a barebones approach with a simple foreach? Are you looking for a 1-line solution, or something more complicated, or ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`uasort()`](https://php.net/uasort) to sort your array. Then, you could get the first key using [`key()`](https://php.net/key).

```
$array = array(
    'utrecht_cs' => array(
        'name' => 'utrecht_cs',
        'address' => '3511 AX Utrecht, Netherlands',
        'distance' => 95
    ),
    'groningen_cs' => array(
        'name' => 'groningen_cs',
        'address' => '9726 AC Groningen, Netherlands',
        'distance' => '102.47'
    ),
    'zwolle_cs' => array(
        'name' => 'zwolle_cs',
        'address' => '8011 CW Zwolle, Netherlands',
        'distance' => '2.54'
    )
);

uasort($array, function($a, $b) { return $a['distance'] <=> $b['distance']; });
$first_key = key($array);
```

Output:

```
zwolle_cs
```

You can also use (for PHP version before 7.0):

```
uasort($array, function($a, $b) { 
   return $a['distance'] < $b['distance'] ? -1 : 1; 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative sorting. Extract the `distance` column from the array and sort on that, sorting the original array based that:

```
array_multisort(array_column($array, 'distance'), $array);
$result = key($array);
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use `usort` to sort your multidimensional array.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php

```
function sortNumbers($a, $b)
{
    return $a['distance'] <=> $b['distance'];
}

usort($yourArray,'sortNumbers');
```

Read this for more info https://delboy1978uk.wordpress.com/2012/09/19/sorting-multidimensional-arrays-using-php/